# My android code can work successfully on Android 2.2, However can't work in Android 4.2.2

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, android-canvas

My project of Android is  a YUV player
At first, the project can work successfully for the Android 2.2 version
However when I want it can also work on Android 4.2.2
some problem happen

It still can run smoothly without error message
However the content of YUV image wasn't be shown on the screen
the content of screen is just block 
here is my Java code,it receive the YUV data which comes from JNI, and display the content:

```
public class SkiaView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
private SurfaceHolder holder=null;//******Version2******//
private static final String TAG = "skiademo";

private int mSampleId = 0;
final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 352, 288);  

int FrameNum=0;

static 
{
    System.loadLibrary("SkiaDemo");
}

public native void renderHello(Canvas canvas, int FrameNum,Rect rect);
public native void renderText(Canvas canvas);

public SkiaView(Context context,AttributeSet attr)//******Version2******//
{
       super(context,attr);
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
       holder=getHolder();
       holder.addCallback(this);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)//******Version2******//
{
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       new Thread(new MyLoop()).start();
}

class MyLoop implements Runnable//******Version2******//
{
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(true){
            try{
                Canvas c=holder.lockCanvas();
                if(FrameNum == 15)
                {
                    FrameNum = 0;
                    renderHello(c, FrameNum,rect);
                    //c.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
                }
                else
                {
                    FrameNum = FrameNum + 1;
                    renderHello(c, FrameNum,rect);
                    //c.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
                }
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                Thread.sleep(1);
                }catch(Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

and the following is my Code which read the content of YUV
and return it back to JAVA

```
#include "SkiaDemoJni.h"
#include "mylog.h"

#include "GraphicsJNI.h"
#include "SkPaint.h"
#include "SkCanvas.h"

#include"opj_includes.h"
#include <wchar.h>
#include <android\log.h> 
#include <android\bitmap.h>

#define two_pi (6.283)

unsigned char cur_image_y[101376];
unsigned char cur_image_u[101376];
unsigned char cur_image_v[101376];

inline int32_t color(int32_t pColorY,int32_t pColorU,int32_t pColorV) {
  int32_t pColorR;
  int32_t pColorG;
  int32_t pColorB;
  pColorR = pColorY+1.4075*(pColorV-128);
  pColorG = pColorY-0.3455*(pColorU-128)-0.7169*(pColorV-128);
  pColorB = pColorY+1.7790*(pColorU-128);
  if(pColorR>255)
   pColorR=255;
  if(pColorG>255)
   pColorG=255;
  if(pColorB>255)
   pColorB=255;   

  if(pColorR<0)
   pColorR=0;
  if(pColorG<0)
   pColorG=0;
  if(pColorB<0)
   pColorB=0;     

   return 0xFF000000 | ((pColorB << 16) & 0x00FF0000) | ((pColorG << 8) & 0x0000FF00) |       
   ((pColorR) & 0x000000FF);
   }
void Java_com_whtr_example_skiademo_SkiaView_renderHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thizz,     
jobject canvas, jint FrameNum,jobject rect)
{   
jclass bitmapConfig = env->FindClass("android/graphics/Bitmap$Config");
jfieldID rgb565FieldID = env->GetStaticFieldID(bitmapConfig, "ARGB_8888",   
"Landroid/graphics/Bitmap$Config;");
jobject rgb565Obj = env->GetStaticObjectField(bitmapConfig, rgb565FieldID); 
LOGD("jclass bitmapClass ");
jclass bitmapClass = env->FindClass("android/graphics/Bitmap");
jmethodID createBitmapMethodID = env->GetStaticMethodID(bitmapClass,"createBitmap", 
 "(IILandroid/graphics/Bitmap$Config;)Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;");
jobject bitmapObj = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(bitmapClass, createBitmapMethodID,  
 352, 288, rgb565Obj);//width,height 
int a[101376]={0};
AndroidBitmapInfo   info;   
int*                pixels;
 int                ret;    
 ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmapObj, &info);    
 ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmapObj, (void**)&pixels);       
 int                width=(int)info.width;  
 int                height=(int)info.height;
 SkBitmap bmp = SkBitmap();  
 bmp.setConfig(SkBitmap::kARGB_8888_Config,width,height);   
 bmp.setPixels((void*)pixels);
SkCanvas background(bmp);
SkCanvas* canv = GraphicsJNI::getNativeCanvas(env, canvas);
if (!canv)
{
    LOGE("!canv");
    return;
} 
systemPara sys;   

  sys.width = 352;

  sys.height = 288;
  sys.frameNO = 1;
  sys.startFrm = 0;
sys.inFileName = new char[strlen("/mnt/sdcard/out_352x288_P420_final.yuv")+1];
   strcpy(sys.inFileName, "/mnt/sdcard/out_352x288_P420_final.yuv");
for(int i=0;i<sys.frameNO;i++){
    //sys.startFrm = i;
    YUV_play_read(cur_image_y, cur_image_u, cur_image_v, sys.inFileName, sys.width, sys.height, FrameNum);
    for(int x=0;x<sys.width;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<sys.height;y++){
            a[x + y * 352] = color(cur_image_y[x + y * 352], cur_image_u[x + y * 352], cur_image_v[x + y * 352]);
        }
    }
}  
pixels = a;
AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmapObj);
bmp.setPixels((void*)pixels);
canv->drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, NULL);

  }
```

The following is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.whtr.example.skiademo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
             android:targetSdkVersion="17"></uses-sdk>
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

and the following is my Application.mk
     APP_PLATFORM := android-8

Comment: You should better describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: sorry, I want to run my project on Android 4.2.2
My project can run successfully on Android 2.2
But can't work normally on Android 4.2.2

Comment: There is one brace to much after </uses-sdk> in your manifest.

Comment: Thank you
I modified it,but it still dosen't work

Comment: I think whether if the problem occurs due to the skia library
Maybe Android 4 can't use skia library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go in AndroidManifest.xml and replace your uses-sdk tag by the following tag

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

For more help visit http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html

Comment: Thank you, I have modified my AndroidManifest.xml 
however, it still can't work

Comment: I post my AndroidManifest.xml
could you give me a favor to check it whether if it is OK or not?

Comment: Thank you, the problem still exist, but I choose you as the best answer

Comment: Would you tell me what your uses-sdk tag looked like before this change?

Comment: Like this:
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"/>

Comment: I think it is because I use skia libray, and in Android 4.2.2 it redefined the skia library.
So the project cannot run successfully

Comment: The Java code can run as usual
however JAVA cannot receive data from JNI, which should give the canvas contains YUV data to JAVA

Comment: Is there exists any needs to modify the Application.mk?

Comment: Bro, why don't you try OpenGL for this? I will recommend you OpenGL for this.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, although I still cannot understand why the problem occurs
I rewrite the code in another method
Now it can run successfully